# Failed to cast variant value to DATE (parquet/snowflake)

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, parquet, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Pandas dataframe which includes two `datetime64[ns]` columns, one with just a date and the other with a timestamp.

```py
>>> df
          date                     ts
0   2020-01-06    2020-01-06 03:12:45
1   2020-01-07    2020-01-07 12:56:52
2   2020-01-08    2020-01-08 15:09:59

>>> df.info()
#   Column       Dtype
--- ---------     ------------
0   date         datetime64[ns]
1   ts           datetime64[ns]
```

The idea is to save this dataframe into a Parquet file hosted on S3:

```py
df.to_parquet('s3:/my-bucket-name/df.parquet', engine='fastparquet', compression='gzip')
```

... and using this file to `COPY INTO` a Snowflake table with two columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    date DATE,
    ts TIMESTAMP
)
```

The command used to `COPY` is as follows, based on Snowflake's documentation:

```sql
copy into {schema}.{table}
    from s3://my-bucket-name
    credentials=(aws_key_id='{aws_key_id}' aws_secret_key='{aws_secret_key}')
    match_by_column_name=case_insensitive
    file_format=(type=parquet);
```

When executing the above command with a dataframe/file/table with only `timestamp` fields, everything runs fine. The problem comes when using it with a dataframe/file/table with a `date` field. In this case, an error shows up:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100071 (22000):
Failed to cast variant value "2020-06-16 00:00:00.000" to DATE
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake - COPY INTO ... ignores DATE\_INPUT\_FORMAT setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939636/snowflake-copy-into-ignores-date-input-format-setting)

Comment: One way I can think here is in the Copy command try to select the record from the s3 and then cast it to TO_DATE(). create the select statement and see if that works if yes then add it to your copy statement. Let me know.