# Snowflake - COPY INTO ... ignores DATE_INPUT_FORMAT setting

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following instruction aims at using a specific format to import DATEs

```
alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

However, it seems to have no effect on the following:

```
copy into schema.table
    from s3://bucket/file.parquet
    credentials=(aws_key_id='...' aws_secret_key='...')
    match_by_column_name=case_insensitive
    file_format=(type=parquet);
```

Which results in errors like below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100071 (22000):
Failed to cast variant value "2020-06-16 00:00:00.000" to DATE
```

When a column in the imported Parquet file has a format as specified above for a date field.

This really sounds like a bug, as the above `COPY INTO` scenario should in theory be a typical use case for altering the `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`.

Is there a way to address this?

Answer (score 1):

The DATE_INPUT_FORMAT should affect the copy command.  The documentation talks about not supporting a timestamp from a variant column on a date conversion.

> Although TO_DATE accepts a TIMESTAMP value, it does not accept a TIMESTAMP inside a VARIANT.

Comment: interesting — this is a bit surprising as the Parquet file in question has been created from a Pandas dataframe which absolutely has a `datetime64[ns]` data type.

Comment: What is the data type in the snowflake target table?

Comment: It is a `DATE` column — I'm not sure why Snowflake identifies the Parquet field in question as VARIANT — maybe Pandas/fastparquet are not doing their job properly

Comment: Snowflake reads Parquet data into a single VARIANT column. You can query the data in a VARIANT column just as you would JSON data, using similar commands and functions.

Comment: ah right — but then we'd lose the benefit of automated column name matching... unless we're able to transform only ONE column (this `date` column in question) to cast it into a TIMESTAMP and leave the rest be...

Comment: e.g. import "my_single_variant_column.date_field::timestamp AS date_field" and leave the rest untouched, which avoids having to write (and most importantly maintain) a painfully long list of imported fields

Comment: if you have any idea on how to achieve this without listing all the fields in the `COPY INTO` statement, I'm all ears — otherwise we're just going to stick with a TIMESTAMP column for now — not elegant/ideal, but will do the trick

Comment: @Jivan A slightly side-question for you.  If the parquet file is created using Pandas, then are you leveraging the `write_pandas()` function to load the data to Snowflake?